# Error while running Variable distance buffer in QGIS 3.12

Tags: buffer, qgis-3

I have problem in QGIS 3.12 when I try to use the tool Variable distance buffer I get an Error.
This is the log message I get from the error:

> { 'BUFFER' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'DARC' : 5, 'DISSOLVE ' : False,
>   'DIST_FIELD' : 'raduis', 'DIST_SCALE' : 1, 'NZONES' : 1, 'POLY_INNER '
>   : False, 'SHAPES' : 'C:\Users\Public\shape5.shp|layername=shape5' }
>
> shapes_tools "Shapes Buffer" -SHAPES "C:\Users\Public\shape5.shp"
>   -DIST_FIELD "raduis" -DIST_SCALE 1.0 -NZONES 1 -DARC 5.0 -DISSOLVE false -POLY_INNER false -BUFFER
>   "C:/Users/לירון/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_sFcGXG/44994fdb08b0468883ff9936f0c2a56e/BUFFER.shp"
>
> Execution completed in 10.89 seconds Results: {'BUFFER':
>   'C:/Users/לירון/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_sFcGXG/44994fdb08b0468883ff9936f0c2a56e/BUFFER.shp'}

How can I solve it?

Comment: Try using a folder without special charachters in path `ירון/`

Comment: What BERA says, this is most likely the error source.